# AngularJS : How to pass multiple parameters to controller through ng-href?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I've a table containing edit button to update the record. When I'm passing single `id` to `ng-href` its working fine and opening form page:

Ex: In my `index.html` table

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-href="#/provider/{{row._id}}">Edit</a>
```

But I want to pass one more parameter along with `row._id` to ng-href like:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-href="#/provider/{{row._id}}/collectionName/{{collectionName}}">Edit</a>
```

Its not working and redirecting to home page.

Here's my controller:

```
    $timeout(function () {
        if ($routeParams.id !== undefined) {                
            $http.get('/providerlist/'+$routeParams.id, {
                params:{
                    id:$routeParams.id, 
                    collectionName:$routeParams.collectionName
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                alert(response);
                $scope.providerList = response;
                $scope.id = response['_id'];
            });
        }
    });
```

`app.js` for routing:

```
var ProviderApp = angular.module('ProviderApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home/index.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'home'
    })

    .when('/provider', {                            
        templateUrl: 'templates/provider/index.html',
        controller: 'ProviderController',
        controllerAs: 'provider'
    })                        
    .when('/provider/:id', {                            
        templateUrl: 'templates/provider/form.html',
        controller: 'ProviderController',
        controllerAs: 'provider'
    })                        
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

Here what exactly I want to do is after clicking on `edit` button it should redirect to `form.html` with parameter/data of `id` and `collectionName`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to change the '/provider/:id'...to something like ...'/provider/:id/collection/:collectionName' and then use those param in controllers... using $routeParams....

Comment: @damitj07: I tried `.when('/provider/:id/collection/:collectionName', {                            
        templateUrl: 'templates/provider/form.html',
        controller: 'ProviderController',
        controllerAs: 'provider'
    })` but its not working

Comment: I think that is because you have two roues **/provider/...** with same name...

Comment: @damitj07: Yes.. but both are different. 2nd one is taking parameter 1st one is not

Comment: yes But I think as you are mapping multiple routes.. to same controller function..there might a be an issue in parameter handling..
you can try to modify one of them and check if it works...

Comment: @damitj07: I tried by changing name from `providerlist` to `collectionlist` but still problem persist

Comment: NO I mean try commenting the .when('/provider', {                            
        templateUrl: 'templates/provider/index.html',..... and then change the below one to what I said before..to check if that works..then you may know what the issue ..is ...

Comment: @damitj07: same issue :(

Comment: can you post  sample url your hitting

Comment: @damitj07: url is the same which I've posted for `edit` button

Comment: This One: `<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-href="#/provider/{{row._id}}/collectionName/{{collectionName}}">Edit</a>
`

Comment: Now I've changed name `provider` to `collectiondata` : `<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-href="#/collectiondata/{{row._id}}/collectionName/{{collectionName}}">Edit</a>`

Comment: I mean an actual url which is getting hit ...when you press Edit in your address bar..If it containes forward slash ..then that might be an issue..

Comment: @damitj07: This is actual url before hitting `edit` button : `http://localhost:1000/#/provider` and when I click on `edit` button it goes into : `http://localhost:1000/#/home`

Comment: @damitj07: is it possible using ng-click if not with ng-href?

Comment: that is because the ngRoute redirects to home..if it encounters any invalid url... as you have defined in your router config...
ok.. Can you send what is data in {{row._id }} and {{collectionName}}

Comment: Yes you can use ng-click...but even in that case you have to form a proper URL to get to page you want..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use multiple params in `ng-href` you should also update your route url in `app.js`.

when you used multiple parameters in `ng-href` but no route matching with this route then worked `otherwise` route that redirect to `home`.

you can try it.

in html:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-href="#/provider/{{row._id}}/collectionName/{{collectionName}}">Edit</a>
```

add a route in `app.js` like

```
.when('/provider/:id/collectionName/:cName', {                            
        templateUrl: 'templates/provider/form.html',
        controller: 'YourController'
    });
```

and in controller need to change like:

```
 $http.get('/providerlist/'+$routeParams.id +'/collectionName/'+ $routeParams.cName)
 .success(function (response) {
     alert(response);
     $scope.providerList = response;
     $scope.id = response['_id'];
 });
```

so server side route should be like:  `/providerlist/:id/collectionName/:cName`

Comment: Wrote exactly like this but its not working.. what should I write in controller after this?

Comment: ohh great.. that's what I was missing.. updated my code and its working now.. thanks shaishab..!!!

Answer (score 1):

The path in ngRoute path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a star like  :name* , All characters are eagerly stored in **$routeParams** under the given name when the route matches.

For example, routes like : **/color/:color/largecode/:largecode*/edit**

For this sample URL : **/color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashes/edit**

And extract:

> **color**: brown
>
> **largecode**: code/with/slashes.

So in your case it the Route will be

```
.when('/provider/:id*\/collectionName/:collectionName*\', {                            
        templateUrl: 'templates/provider/form.html',
        controller: 'ProviderController',
        controllerAs: 'provider'
    })
```

This will ensure that even if there are special characters and forward slashes in your resultant href link you are redirected to proper controller and page...