# How to append query string to url in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, location, query-string

I am new to angular js. I have search page with input text box to search for customerId but I want to add a functionality where I can search based on url string as well.

For example,  My url is :

```
http://localhost:8080/#/search
```

But I need something like

```
http://localhost:8080/#/search?ACC34ff
```

http://localhost:8080/#/search?CustomerId so that I can search based on customerId in url also

Can some one tell how can I add query string ?

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'homePageCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: true
    }).when('/features', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/features.html',
        controller: 'featuresCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    }).when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/search.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

Controller :

```
appControllers.controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope','$route','$filter', '$http', '$location','$window','$timeout',
    function($scope, $route, $filter, $http, $location, $window, $timeout) {

        $scope.searchCustomerFeatures = function () {

            if($scope.customerId != null) {

            $http.get('/getCustomerFeatures.do', {params: {'customerId': $scope.customerId}}).success(function (data) {

                $scope.featuresJson = angular.toJson(data, true);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Html :

```
  <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/search')}" style="margin-left: 100px; text-decoration-color: black; font-size: 20px">
            <a href="#search" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search</a>
        </li >
```

Search page :

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I can't believe you haven't got more answers because there are many ways to pass and retrieve a variable over the url, each being slight variations of 2 main ways.

1. As part of a **Query String** (as per your request)
2. As a **Route Parameter** (also worth mentioning)

The subsequent examples assume that you have a text input for customer id as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customerId" />
```

**1) How to pass `customerId` as part of a Query String**

Append `?cId={{ customerId }}` to your link as follows:

```
<a href="#search?cId={{ customerId }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search</a>
```

Now when you click on the link you will be taken to a url such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/search?cId=ACC34ff
```

You can then pick the `cId` parameter up in the controller by using the [**`$location`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service.

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $location){
    var qsCustomerId = $location.search().cId;
    // Do what you want with qsCustomerId here... 
});
```

**2) How to pass `customerId` as a Route Parameter**

Create a new route that specifies a new `cId` route parameter:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/search/:cId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/search.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
}]);
```

Append `/{{ customerId }}` to your link as follows:

```
<a href="#search/{{ customerId }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search</a>
```

Now when you click on the link you will be taken to a url such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/search/ACC34ff
```

You can pick the `cId` parameter up in the controller using the [**`$routeParams`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) service.

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $routeParmas){
    var rpCustomerId = $routeParmas.cId;
    // Do what you want with rpCustomerId here... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to pass the customerId as a parameter.

```
.when('/Search', {
        templateUrl: function (params) { return 'partials/search?customer=' + params.CustomerId; }
    })
```

In the follow link there is also an explanation on how to pass multiple parameters, in case you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35967896/5988277

Comment: I don't need anything on the controller side thn ? I am not clear on how it will use the customerID

Comment: Also how do I router when the user uses the url itself like http://localhost:8080/#/search?ACC34ff  instead of http://localhost:8080/#/search

Comment: My bad. You need to set the controller to read the parameter. $http.get('/Search/'+$routeParams.customerId)
 .success(function (response) {
     ....
 });