# Pass 2 different parameter i.e. Id and Name in angularJS Routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-1.6

Pass 2 parameter in url using routing in Angularjs.

i.e. i want the url is like `/Business/Industry/3/Aviation`

Here is the MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult Industry(int ServicesId, string Servicesname = "")
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Here is the anchor tag:

```
 <a href="#/Industry/{{list.Id}}/{{list.IndustryName}}">
```

Note:Both are dynamically list.Id and list.IndustryName

Here is the angular routing:

I have try the below but not correct.

can anyone tell me how to do.
How to call by routing.

```
.when('/Business/Industry/:Id', { templateUrl: '/Business/Industry', controller: 'BusinessIndustry' });
```

Comment: check this link :-    

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967305/angularjs-how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-controller-through-ng-href

Comment: Is there any solution to pass two parameter in angularjs routing?

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there:

```
.when('/view2/:pqid/:cid'
```

maps to a URL in this format :

```
view2/1234/4567
```

1234 being the pqid and 4567 the cid.

So your routing, I think is working, just change the link to #/view2/775/4.

Or if you want to keep the same link change your routing to:

```
#/view2/pqid/:pqid/cid/:cid
```

Comment: in Industry mvc controller there are two parameter one is int and another one is string..okay..and what is the href in the anchor tag?